# Push a button to load reviews

Tags: selenium, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape reviews from this site:

https://www.bbb.org/sacramento/business-reviews/heating-and-air-conditioning/elite-heating-air-conditioning-in-elk-grove-ca-47012326/reviews-and-complaints

But the content of the reviews isn't been loaded with by scrapy.
I tried then to use selenium to push the button and load the content:

```
url = 'https://www.bbb.org/losangelessiliconvalley/business-reviews/plumbers/bryco-plumbing-in-chatsworth-ca-13096711/reviews-and-complaints'
driver_1 = webdriver.Firefox()
driver_1.get(url)
content = driver_1.page_source
REVIEWS_BUTTON = '//*[@class="button orange first"]'
button = driver_1.find_element_by_xpath(REVIEWS_BUTTON)
button.click()
```

But selenium isn't able to find the button from the above xapth, I'm getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class=\"button orange first\"]"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button located inside an `iframe`, so you need to switch to it first and then handle the button:

```
REVIEWS_BUTTON = '//*[@class="button orange first"]'
driver_1.switch_to_frame('the_iframe') 
button = driver_1.find_element_by_xpath(REVIEWS_BUTTON)
button.click()
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do it using scrapy only?

Comment: Sorry, I have a little experience of working with `Scrapy`, so I don't know for sure